# Casting exception with Entity framework and abstract class

Tags: entity-framework, casting, abstract-class, derived

I´m new in entity framework. I´m using EF6 with VS2013.

I need to implement a database from "code-first" approach.
The problem is that i´m using an abstract class and i can´t understand why the next pice of code doesn´t work:

```
public abstract class AClaseT1
{
    //private int idT1;
    [Key]
    public int idT1
    { get; set; }

}

public class ClaseT1Dev1:AClaseT1
{
    //private int dataT1;
    public int dataT1
    { get; set; }
}

public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AClaseT1> tipos1 { get; set; }        
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Contexto, Configuration>());

        using(var db = new Contexto())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Int for Tipo1:");
            int d = Console.Read();

            ClaseT1Dev1 t1 = new ClaseT1Dev1() { dataT1 = d };
            db.tipos1.Add(t1);
            db.SaveChanges();

            ClaseT1Dev1 query = (ClaseT1Dev1)from t in db.tipos1
                                            select t;

            Console.WriteLine("Int obtenido de Tipo1 metido en BDD: {0}", query.idT1);
            Console.Read();

        }


    }
```

When i run the app, it breaks at the "query" line, because it can´t make the casting... Is there a way to make it works?
I need a table feeded with different derived objects from the base abstract class (i think it is a TPC inheritance approach).

Thanks for your help!!!

**EDIT:**

The exact exception thrown at the "query" line is:

InvalidCastException was unhandled

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in PruebaCodeFirstDB.exe

Additional information: It is not possible to convert an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[PruebaCodeFirstDB.AClaseT1]' to type 'PruebaCodeFirstDB.ClaseT1Dev1'.

Comment: Can you expand on "it breaks"? What is the exception? e.g. "Can't cast etc...

Comment: I´ve just edited my post with the exact exception that i receive.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get the id of the entity you just inserted? Because the id is generated in the database?

Comment: Yep, just testing and learning. Dirty code... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from t in db.tipos1 select t will give you an IEnumerable. You need to change it so that it just returns the one you want